# elasticsearch: Did I lose data when two of my three nodes went down?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 1.7.2 on CentOS

The question: When my nodes B and C went down, did I lose data?

3 node cluster: Nodes: A, B, C

A is master (was set up first, worked out that way). Relevant config (on all nodes, however what happened was the B lost network access and went down, and it turned out that C incorrectly was set to number_of_replicas: 1)

```
node.master: true
node.data: true
index.number_of_shards: 5
index.number_of_replicas: 2
```

On A, while those other two nodes were down, I notice that the "unassigned_shards" is 6. Since my shard count is 5, that implies to me that I have a problem:

```
# curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch-PROD-prod",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 4,
  "active_shards" : 4,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 6,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
}
```

Sure enough, on the shard list below, there is a primary shard (#1) that is UNASSIGNED

```
# curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards
index_v3_PROD 4 p STARTED    22578283 12.7gb 10.208.131.56 PROD-node-3a
index_v3_PROD 4 r UNASSIGNED                                   
index_v3_PROD 0 p STARTED    22572884 12.7gb 10.208.131.56 PROD-node-3a
index_v3_PROD 0 r UNASSIGNED                                   
index_v3_PROD 3 p STARTED    22579159 12.8gb 10.208.131.56 PROD-node-3a
index_v3_PROD 3 r UNASSIGNED                                   
index_v3_PROD 1 p UNASSIGNED                                   
index_v3_PROD 1 r UNASSIGNED                                   
index_v3_PROD 2 p STARTED    22580877 12.7gb 10.208.131.56 PROD-node-3a
index_v3_PROD 2 r UNASSIGNED
```

**Notice above that shard 1 is "p" and is UNASSIGNED. This looks scary to me!**

I then used a reroute command to assign it over to A, which it did.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute' -d '{"commands" : [ {
              "allocate" : {
                  "index" : "index_v3_PROD", 
                  "shard" : 1, 
                  "node" : "PROD-node-3a", 
                  "allow_primary" : true
              }
            }
        ]
    }'
```

But shard 1 started at a very small size and then kind of grew (I think from new data being sent to ES). I have a strong feeling that shard 1 data was lost.

Can someone confirm whether shard 1 data looks suspect/lost (or not)?

Comment: I only see this `"number_of_nodes" : 1` so only one node was available in the cluster. You said that only B went down. How come `"number_of_nodes"` is `1` then?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Please re-read line 2 and 3 of OP

Comment: What `reroute` command did you use exactly?

Comment: @AndreiStefan OP enhanced w reroute command.  What is the answer to the main question? (was data lost?)

Comment: Yes, it was. A `reroute` command for a primary shard that has `"allow_primary": true` and that shard is not available will start the shard from scratch, empty. You should have made everything possible to bring that node back in the cluster. In your [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374047/elasticsearch-how-to-reinitialize-a-node) I asked your for the log files hoping to find out why the nodes are not able to join the cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrei posted this as a comment, not as an answer, so I will:

Yes, data was lost.

A reroute command for a primary shard that has "allow_primary": true and that shard is not available will start the shard from scratch, empty. You should have made everything possible to bring that node back in the cluster.

---

The footnote here is: We did not know what to do to bring back a cluster node. The other 2 nodes showed this status:

```
# curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true
{
  "error" : "MasterNotDiscoveredException[waited for [30s]]",
  "status" : 503
}
```

We could not find any diag steps to use, and the logs showed us nothing useful. Two nodes both reported this issue (there are 3 total, so the only copy of the needed shard was on one of those two).

We verified all-way network communication, and rebooted the other nodes, but they did not attach to the cluster.

Ultimately, we set up a fresh 3 node cluster, and are being better about ensuring that every node has every shard present, so that the cluster could withstand losing 2 nodes.